# In IE11, element is displayed only on hover but not when loaded first?

Tags: css, hover, internet-explorer-11, oracle-jet

I am facing problems with IE11 where CSS not loading completely or not applied or crossed out by the browser. This specific problem I am working on oracle JET application. Specifically, content of few rows of the oj-table is not displayed.

If I hover over the empty row, content shows up. 
If I toggle any CSS property of the row from the developer tool, content shows up.

We have huge style-sheet file. 
To optimize i tried splitting the file, but no luck.
Tried adding a property to the row, no luck.

Comment: Only description of the issue will not help us to find the cause for the issue. It will be better if you try to provide any sample code with detailed steps to produce the issue. Also you can try to post the snapshot of the issue from IE and other browsers. It can help us to understand the issue in better way. Try to use the developer tools to check the applied styles on the element. It can help you to find any issue with specific css code. You can try to compare it with the applied styles in other browser may help you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Deepak-MSFT. I tried using developer tools that applied the styles, but with no luck. I ended up refreshing the oj-table after the rows has been updated following the service call.

Comment: Work around is to invoke refresh on the oj-table. https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojTable.html#refresh

Comment: Thanks for commenting again. I mean you can post a answer not a comment. Than you will have an option to mark it as an answer. It can be beneficial to other users who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work around is to invoke refresh on the oj-table. 
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojTable.html#refresh